# How to update database when changes happen in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I've question to ask.

I want to update table at backend in database through making changes in datagridview.
DataGridView changes should be reflected into the Database.

How can I achieve it?

Thank you...

Codes:

```
SqlCommand command;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();

            string updateQuery = @"UPDATE Hucre set VericiKB=@VericiKB Where OrtamKB=@OrtamKimlikBilgisi and HucreKB=@HucreKB";
            command = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, con);

            command.Parameters.Add("@VericiKB", SqlDbType.Int, 50, "VericiKB");
            SqlParameter param1 = command.Parameters.Add("@HucreKB", SqlDbType.Int, 50, "HucreKB");
            SqlParameter param2 = command.Parameters.Add("@OrtamKB", SqlDbType.Int, 50, "OrtamKB");

            param1.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
            param2.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

            da.UpdateCommand = command;
```

Comment: You can ahcieve that by adding Insert, Update, or Delete Commands/ Events what have you tried so far..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Hi, tried but couldn't succeed..

Comment: What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please paste an example of the code you tried.. examples like how are you binding the DataGridview via the sql.. are you using DataAdapters..ect...??/

Comment: I'm trying to add my codes, but it doesn't update..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I've added my codes...

Comment: You have to do ExecuteNoQuery looks like you are not executing the code

Comment: can you edit your initial post and paste in the full method where you are trying to execute the code.. ? It would helpout a lot..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where or what is da.UpDateCommand = command;..?
within that

refactor your code by wrapping Try Catch {} blocks

```
SqlCommand command = null;
try
{
  if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
  {
      con.Open();
  }

  string updateQuery = @"UPDATE Hucre set VericiKB=@VericiKB 
         WHERE OrtamKB=@OrtamKimlikBilgisi and HucreKB=@HucreKB";
  command = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, con);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VericiKB", "VericiKB");//pass a variable here 
  SqlParameter param1 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HucreKB", "HucreKB");//pass a variable here
  SqlParameter param2 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrtamKB", "OrtamKB");//pass a variable here
  param1.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
  param2.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
  //what is this ..??? da.UpdateCommand = command;
  command.ExecuteNonQuery;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    //Write or trap your exception here..
 }
```

//when you are done release the SQLCommand objects

Comment: if you are trying to do caching with  DataRowVersion.Original why..? try to execute the simple update first so that we can eliminate what or where the other errors are happening..

Answer (score 0):

just add the databinding like

```
this.domainUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _user, "Active", true);
```

This example is for Entity Framework. For EF you must call

```
_repository.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges()
```

before closing the form, or after changing the value